# Inline font color based on keyvalue in angular template?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have an array of objects:

```
var objects = [{'item':'A','type':'Sport'},{'item':'B','type':'Rock'}]
```

I want to make it so that if the type is Sport, set "color:red" for that div. If type is "Rock", then set "color:gray" for that div.

How do I do something like this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in objects">
   <div style="color:red if item.type='Sport', color:gray if item.type='Rock'">{{item.item}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I like to do in those cases, make CSS classes and concatenate the class name to use it ... like this:

CSS

```
.type-sport {
   color: red;
}

.type-rock {
   color: gray;
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="item in objects">
   <div class="type-{{:: item.type.toLowerCase() }}">{{item.item}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also added one-way binding for the example (::) to save watches and avoid to affect performance but if you need two-way binding just remove it

Comment: Syntactically, what is the "::"?

Comment: An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two condition then you can acheive it by following code

```
<div ng-style="item.type === 'Sport' && {'color':'red'}  || item.type === 'Rock' && {'color':'gray'}"</div>
```

if you have more than two condition to compare then use following code

```
<div ng-if="'Sport'==item.type"
              ng-style="{color:'red'}"></div>
<div ng-if="'Rock'!=item.type"
              ng-style="{color:'red'}"></div>
```

..other conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution:

```
<style>
   .red-div{
     color: red;
   }

   .gray-div {
     color: gray;
   }
</style>

<div ng-repeat="item in objects">
   <div  ng-class="{'red-div': item.type=='Sport', 'gray-div': item.type=='Rock'}">{{item.item}}</div>
</div>
```